# Programmatically firing a segue from dynamic cells

Tags: dynamic, uitableview, ios6, segue

I have two grouped sections, each containing one cell view. I need one cell, when clicked, to go to one scene and the other cell to go to another. I have set up the segues from the main view controller to the two other scenes and now I need to instruct the program to fire the segue when the correct cell has been clicked.

I think this has to happen in this area of my code where each section is customized.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *serverLocCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"serverLocation"];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            serverLocCell.textLabel.text = testLocation;
            serverLocCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Change";
            break;
        case 1:
            serverLocCell.textLabel.text = @"Speed Test";
            serverLocCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Change";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return serverLocCell;
}
```

I think I also require this function:

```
self preformSegueWithIdentifier
```

However can't quite nail down the correct code/placement.

Both segues have their own identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that you need the performSegueWithIdentifier. You need this method to trigger a segue programmatically, which is required in your case.

You will need the table view delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath to call the performSegueWithIdentifier with the correct identifier based on the cell tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourFirstIdentifier" sender:nil];
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSecondIdentifier" sender:nil];
    }
}
```